# CORS issue while authenticating an external web app to Salesforce

Tags: website-integration, cors

I'm trying to authenticate to saleforce using Connected App and web application, My request succeed with Postman but when I try send the request from the Web App I get CORS issue and OAuth unsupported_grant_type error

I already added localhost to CORS whitelist in my Salesforce Org and even hosted the web app in heroku, but still get the same ERROR !
here are the screenshots
[image] 
[image]

i'm still stucked whith this for 2 wekks, please Help.
Thank you :)

Comment: For web apps, it is advised to use the [OAuth web server flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5). CORS in not supported by login endpoints. Also if these are you actual credentials, please remove them from screenshot. The other way would be to have a backend Node JS or something else to make that request on behalf of browser.

Comment: thanks for your anwer , but in my case I should use username-pasword flow , and I can't figure it out !

Comment: Then you may need to have a backend server to make this call on behalf of your browser to make sure you are not violating CORS and also should secure the website with a HTTPS.

Comment: I already did that, it works but not really what I wanna do, because I'll have problems with performance !

Comment: In that case you need to make sure that my domain is enabled and CORS is enabled for auth endpoints. See here https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_endpoints_cors.htm&type=5. Then make sure that the auth request is sent to domain url instead of login.salesforce.com.